# Unable to run markdown - error for code with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I was trying out a set of codes from the book R for Data Science, which seem to be running perfectly fine in the console. However , when I try to compile it as a markdown, I'm unable to proceed & am getting the following error :

```
Error in -title: invalid argument to unary operator Calls: ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution halted
```

Comment: Can you show us your markdown header? My guess is that it has some invalid expression.

Comment: Hi, the error message alone wont cut it - you should provide us with the code you tried.